# Подсветка HTML и CSS синтаксиса в Visual Studio

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, visual-studio

Открывая файлы веб-проекта (HTML, CSS), мы видим только подсветку тегов, но тут я вспоминаю Sublime Text 3 или Visual Studio Code от Microsoft, в которых все подсвечивается по разному. В HTML: URL, классы и ID, а в CSS: цвета, URL, значения свойств и т.д. Так вот, как можно сделать подсветку синтаксиса этих файлов?

Чтобы понять что я имею ввиду, попробуйте открыть один и тот же HTML файл в Visual Studio и в каком-нибудь другом редакторе, например Sublime text 3

Comment: @LFC_Red Я имею ввиду, чтобы не было 2 цвета голубой и белый, а побольше, например все строки обернутые в кавычки подсвечиваются зеленым все доп свойства типа href, src, class, id и т.п другим и все в таком духе

Comment: Всё можно. В vscode есть темы. Если парсер уже достаточно классов выставляет, то просто тему, если нет, то надо как-то как кастомный тип регистрировать - он же умеет подсветку незнакомых типов файлов, если расширение стоит.

Comment: Так в VS или в VS Code?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я знаю про vscode, но я спрашивал не про него, а про обычную студию, просто один пользователь не понял до конца вопрос и сделал свою правку

Comment: В VS тоже есть расширения.. Но вообще-то не знаю...

Comment: @LFC_Red Я имел ввиду именно visual studio. НЕ code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример проверен на Visual Studio 2017
Чтоб внести изменения в подсветку Visual Studio (её цветовую гамму), необходимо зайти в

```
Настройки (Options)-> Окружение (Environment) -> Шрифты и цвета (Fonts and Colors)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Подробная инструкция есть на MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/reference/fonts-and-colors-environment-options-dialog-box?view=vs-2017)

Пример (извиняюсь за ядерные цвета, просто для наглядности сделал):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Также можно темами менять в `Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online -> VS Marketplace`, но темы влияют на всю подсветку Студии (т.е. на все ЯП)

Answer (score -1):

You can install Sublime VSCode Theme Extend inside VisualStudioCode Application
Вы можете установить раширение [Sublime VSCode Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yurihs.sublime-vscode-theme) в приложение Visual Studio Code.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, переведите ответ на русский язык. сделать ответ можно, нажав [edit]